# Importing big tecplot block files in python as fast as possible

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to import in python some ascii file ( from tecplot, software for cfd post processing). 
Rules for those files are (at least, for those that I need to import):

- The file is divided in several section

Each section has two lines as header like:

```
VARIABLES = "x" "y" "z" "ro" "rovx" "rovy" "rovz" "roE" "M" "p" "Pi" "tsta" "tgen" 
ZONE T="Window(s) : E_W_Block0002_ALL",  I=29,  J=17,  K=25, F=BLOCK
```

- Each section has a set of variable given by the first line. When a section ends, a new section starts with two similar lines.
- For each variable there are I*J*K values.
- Each variable is a continous block of values.
- There are a fixed number of values per row (6).
- When a variable ends, the next one starts in a new line.
- Variables are "IJK ordered data".The I-index varies the fastest; the J-index the next fastest; the K-index the slowest. The I-index should be the inner loop, the K-index shoould be the outer loop, and the J-index the loop in between.

Here is an example of data:

```
VARIABLES = "x" "y" "z" "ro" "rovx" "rovy" "rovz" "roE" "M" "p" "Pi" "tsta" "tgen" 
ZONE T="Window(s) : E_W_Block0002_ALL",  I=29,  J=17,  K=25, F=BLOCK
-3.9999999E+00 -3.3327306E+00 -2.7760824E+00 -2.3117116E+00 -1.9243209E+00 -1.6011492E+00
[...]
0.0000000E+00 #fin first variable
-4.3532482E-02 -4.3584235E-02 -4.3627592E-02 -4.3663762E-02 -4.3693815E-02 -4.3718831E-02 #second variable, 'y'
[...]
1.0738781E-01 #end of second variable
[...]
[...]
VARIABLES = "x" "y" "z" "ro" "rovx" "rovy" "rovz" "roE" "M" "p" "Pi" "tsta" "tgen" #next zone
ZONE T="Window(s) : E_W_Block0003_ALL",  I=17,  J=17,  K=25, F=BLOCK
```

I am quite new at python and I have written a code to import the data to a dictionary, writing the variables as 3D `numpy.array` . Those files could be very big, (up to Gb).  How can I make this code faster? (or more generally, how can I import such files as fast as possible)?

```
import re
from numpy import zeros, array, prod
def vectorr(I,  J,  K):
    """function"""
    vect = []
    for k in range(0,  K):
        for j in range(0, J):
            for i in range(0, I):
                vect.append([i, j, k])
    return vect

a = open('E:\u.dat')

filelist = a.readlines()

NumberCol = 6
count = 0
data = dict()
leng = len(filelist)
countzone = 0
while count < leng:
    strVARIABLES = re.findall('VARIABLES', filelist[count])
    variables = re.findall(r'"(.*?)"',  filelist[count])
    countzone = countzone+1
    data[countzone] = {key:[] for key in variables}
    count = count+1
    strI = re.findall('I=....', filelist[count])
    strI = re.findall('\d+', strI[0]) 
    I = int(strI[0])
    ##
    strJ = re.findall('J=....', filelist[count])
    strJ = re.findall('\d+', strJ[0])
    J = int(strJ[0])
    ##
    strK = re.findall('K=....', filelist[count])
    strK = re.findall('\d+', strK[0])
    K = int(strK[0])
    data[countzone]['indmax'] = array([I, J, K])
    pr = prod(data[countzone]['indmax'])
    lin = pr // NumberCol
    if pr%NumberCol != 0:
        lin = lin+1
    vect = vectorr(I, J, K)
    for key in variables:
        init = zeros((I, J, K))
        for ii in range(0, lin):
            count = count+1
            temp = map(float, filelist[count].split())
            for iii in range(0, len(temp)):
                init.itemset(tuple(vect[ii*6+iii]), temp[iii])
        data[countzone][key] = init
    count = count+1
```

Ps. In python, no cython or other languages

Comment: Change `a = open('E:\8-Documenti\onera stage\u.dat')` to `with open('E:\8-Documenti\onera stage\u.dat') as a` to start with. Second of all your code seems OK, can't see anything striking that would make it very slow. PS: tu fais un stage dans onera? ;)

Comment: Use RunSnakeRun for profiling your code, in order to know where time is spent. I think regular expression on a big files are not a good idea. Try to use PEG instead? Or some custom parsing?

Comment: ehm, I have no idea of what you are tallking about:-). Custom parsing?

Comment: You need at least 75 reputation to start a bounty, which you now have. You should now see the "start a bounty" link below these comments. Good luck!

Comment: How much memory do you have on your computer? If things get very slow you might be using up all your memory (the first f.readlines() call reads everything to memory, and your Numpy data structures are taking up probably just as much). From the looks of the file format you could be reading it sequentially without copying everything to RAM. Like mguijarr proposed, profile your code to find what's making it slow.

Comment: why do you have ascii files several Gb in size? stuff will go much faster if they are stored in a binary format (.fits or similar)

Answer (score 2):

Converting a large bunch of strings to numbers is always going to be a little slow, but assuming the triple-nested for-loop is the bottleneck here maybe changing it to the following gives you a sufficient speedup:

```
# add this line to your imports
from numpy import fromstring

# replace the nested for-loop with:
count += 1
for key in variables:
    str_vector = ' '.join(filelist[count:count+lin])
    ar = fromstring(str_vector, sep=' ')
    ar = ar.reshape((I, J, K), order='F')

    data[countzone][key] = ar 
    count += lin
```

Unfortunately at the moment I only have access to my smartphone (no pc) so I can't test how fast this is or even if it works correctly or at all!

---

**Update**

Finally I got around to doing some testing:

- My code contained a small error, but it does seem to work correctly now.
- The code with the proposed changes runs about 4 times faster than the original
- Your code spends most of its time on `ndarray.itemset` and probably loop overhead and float conversion. Unfortunately cProfile doesn't show this in much detail..
- The improved code spends about 70% of time in `numpy.fromstring`, which, in my view, indicates that this method is reasonably fast for what you can achieve with Python / NumPy.

---

**Update 2**

Of course even better would be to iterate over the file instead of loading everything all at once. In this case this is slightly faster (I tried it) and significantly reduces memory use. You could also try to use multiple CPU cores to do the loading and conversion to floats, but then it becomes difficult to have all the data under one variable. Finally a word of warning: the `fromstring` method that I used scales rather bad with the length of the string. E.g. from a certain string length it becomes more efficient to use something like `np.fromiter(itertools.imap(float, str_vector.split()), dtype=float)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use regular expressions here, there's two things that I would change:

- Compile REs which are used more often (which applies to all REs in your example, I guess). Do `regex=re.compile("<pattern>")` on them, and use the resulting object with `match=regex.match()`, as described in [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re.match#re.match).
- For the I, J, K REs, consider reducing two REs to one, using the grouping feature (also described above), by searching for a pattern of the form "I=(\d+)", and grabbing the part matched inside the parentheses using `regex.group(1)`. Taking this further, you can define a single regex to capture all three variables in one step.

At least for starting the sections, REs seem a bit overkill: There's no variation in the string you need to look for, and `string.find()` is sufficient and probably faster in that case.

EDIT: I just saw you use grouping already for the variables...

Comment: Those are just for parsing the headers of each section. They shouldn't take any significant time compared to actually reading a GB worth of numbers.